# Why MongoDB store the timestamp with -1hour than the actual hour on my computer

Tags: javascript, mongodb, time

I have a collection who contains info about containers and specially the timestamp of when I have read the info (for each elements in the collection). The only problem is that the timestamp is suddenly converted into UTC despite when I read the timestamp it's UTC + 1 (who is the right one).

Someone know from where my problem could comes ?

Maybe it could help you to see the JavaScript:

```
DockerStats.insert({
          read: moment(new Date()).unix(),
          precpu_stats: stat.precpu_stats,
          cpu_stats: stat.cpu_stats,
          memory_stats: stat.memory_stats,
          blkio_stats: stat.blkio_stats,
          pids_stats: stat.pids_stats,
          networks: stat.networks,
});
```

And if I display the read time:

```
1484895487 who is 07:58am
```

But when I read it it's `06:58am` on my client

Comment: To correct that I did on my client JS : `timestamp = ds.read+3600 ` but it's ugly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb stores all time data in utc. So if you use local time, you should convert it back on reading. Or let your mongodb driver to do it. Read more about it (with suggested workaround) here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/model-time-data/

Comment: Ok so it's a right behavior from Mongo. Thank you for the link I'll take a look